# Parse LiveQuery + Redis Scalability

Tags: redis, parse-server

I want to use Live Query on a separate server on Herku. I am looking at the Redis add on and the number of connections. Can someone explain how the number of connection pertains to the how many users can subscribe to the live query.

Actual use case would be to announce to users who is active online in the app. The add ons run $200 per month to support 1024 connections. That sounds expensive, I don't understand if that means that 1024 users subscribing to a class? or if there is some kind of sharing going on between the 1024 connections and the number of users.

Lastly, what would happen if I exceed the connection limit? Would it just timeout with a parse timeout error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redis connections will only be used to connect your parse server's together with the liveQuery servers. Usually you would have them on the same instance, listening to the same port. So let's say you have 10 dynos, you need 20 connections; 1 per publisher (parse-server) + 1 per subscriber , liveQuery server.

To calculate how many users can be connected on a single dyno, it's another story in itself, but you can probably have a look into other websocket + nodejs + heroku literature available on the internet. It's unlikely you'll need 1024 connections, unless you plan having as many dynos.

Comment: Awesome explanation sir. As a followup question, the javascript SDK does not support pointing to a live query server that is separate from the parse server itself. Is this still true? and if so, would it be possible to communicate with the live query server via rest?

Comment: From the code, it doesn't seem anything prevents you from passing another serverURL to the LiveQueryClient https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/LiveQueryClient.js#L136